# Nested attributes and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I find a solution to my problem following many SO answers.
But , i'm not so comfort with Rails magic , and i would understand what happened in my web app.
I explain the context:

I have two model:

```
class Registry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :profession       
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profession 
end

class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :registries
end
```

and a form (for `registry` ) with nested attributes of the `profession` model

```
<%= form_for(@registry) do |f| %>
...
    <%= f.fields_for :profession do |ff| %>
...
```

The problem was , that if i used:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profession do |ff| %>
```

I didn't show the attributes of profession table. Instead ,if i used

```
:professions
```

so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :professions do |ff| %>
```

I see the form. I don't understand why this happened but then , searching on google and on SO , I found that:

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent.

So , maybe this behaviour is caused cause I’m using nested attributes in the child table. But i would have explained better why with `:professions` i saw the attributes of the form and with `:profession` , no.

Now , i fixed the problem using this in the `registries_controller`:

```
def new
  @registry = Registry.new
  @registry.build_profession
end
```

I added the `@registry.build_profession` and now in the form i can use the singular `":profession"`

I don't know what happened...
Can someone explain me these two things? really, i'm not confort with Rails magic..

Also , i have a problem cause if i don't want to insert data in the part of profession form , the profession row is always created in the database. This row is linked by foreign_key to registry row , but is blank (if i don't write nothing in the form , of course). This is really unacceptable..why i have to create a row , before to check if the user put the values..this is not good. I know , nested attribute should be in the **parent** , but i have this necessity to use them in the **child**. Really, rails programmers didin't think this possibility?
I programmed in rails for 6 months , it's not much, i know..but is it possible that everytime i have to fix or discover new things (completely new)??

I'm getting crazy.

EDIT: I'm serching explaination of the problem. Not to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: Nested Attributes, belongs\_to relation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593853/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes-belongs-to-relation)

Comment: I'm serching explaination of the problem. Not to solve it.

Comment: So " This appears to be a documented bug" . Is this meaning that nobody know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you're using the `has_many` association, your controller should be:

```
   def new
     @registry = Registry.new
     @registry.profession.build
   end
```